Invertibility of $A+B$ when $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric and $A$ is invertible
Here is the full assignment:
Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric. In addition, assume that $|\lambda_{amin}(A)|\geq2$ and $|\lambda_{amax}(B)|\leq1$, where $\lambda_{amin}(A)$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ with the smallest absolute value and $\lambda_{amax}(B)$ is the eigenvalue of $B$ with the smallest absolute value.
Show that the matrix $A+B$ is invertible.
Model "solution":
Since $A$ is invertible, $A+B$ is also invertible if
$$||B||_2<\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||_2}.$$
By assumption $||B||_2\leq|\lambda_{amax}(B)|\leq1$, then $A+B$ is invertible.
My thoughts:
I understand that $A$ is invertible but $B$ might not be. I also understand why $||B||_2\leq|\lambda_{amax}(B)|\leq1$.
What I don't understand is how $||B||_2<\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||_2}$ implies that $A+B$ is invertible.
There was also a hint about the fact that any square matrix $A$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix $T$. I have no idea how this is connected to the solution. Help.

Hint: I think writing $A+B = A(I+A^{-1}B)$ is helpful. Consider then the eigenvalues of $(I+A^{-1}B)$. For this, you can use the upper triangular form.

In general, if $\|B\|_2<\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|_2}$, then $\|A^{-1}B\|_2\le\|A^{-1}\|_2\|B\|_2<1$. Therefore, for any unit vector $x$,
\begin{align*}
\|(I+A^{-1}B)x\|_2
&=\|x+A^{-1}Bx\|_2\\
&\ge\|x\|_2-\|A^{-1}Bx\|_2\\
&\ge\|x\|_2-\|A^{-1}B\|_2\,\|x\|_2\\
&=1-\|A^{-1}B\|_2\\
&>0,
\end{align*}
i.e., $(I+A^{-1}B)x\ne0$. It follows that $I+A^{-1}B$ and $A+B$ are nonsingular.
In your case, however, there is no need to consider $A^{-1}$ because we may prove that $(A+B)x\ne0$ directly:
$$
\|(A+B)x\|_2
\ge\|Ax\|_2-\|Bx\|_2
\ge|\lambda_\min(A)|-|\lambda_\max(B)|>0.
$$

How do you get that $$||(A+B)x||_2\geq||Ax||_2-||Bx||_2$$?

@IMM It’s the triangle inequality.
